# 3D Character Animation

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, blender

Hello guys I have been confused for my animation I am creating 3D character animation but I use the another 3d character animation as reference but not using that character or that animation for commercial use I am just referencing it is it will be legal or not? Now insure me that is there will be any problem when is use this animation for commercial use which is just referenced from another character animation

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nohting to do with programming.

Comment: sir i know that all of the things are done with programing but let me give some suggestion

Comment: This question doesn't belong here as it has nothing to do with programming. Maybe ask on https://law.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

There won't be an issue with that. Even, you can get free animations from other websites like https://www.mixamo.com/ and there are a few others, which can also be used for commercials.

Comment: Thank you so much sir for solving my that problem.